# Drop Down menu not working inside the android app

Tags: android, html, drop-down-menu

I have a simple form all the fields work perfectly and the data is also getting stored in
the database. One of the fields is a drop down menu and when I click on the drop down
menu it does not work I am not able to see any option. I have a similar drop down menu
on a different page but it works perfectly, the only difference between the two is that I use 
**method=post** for this one were as I use **method=get** for the other.
Can you guys figure out why the drop down is not working? As there is no console/firebug inside 
the android emulator it is really difficult to debug html , is there an easier way to debug html inside android emulator?

```
<form action="http://abc.com/subscribe/subscribe.tml" method="post">
<select name="Field_3_" style="width: 150px;"> 
    <option value="" selected="selected">Select Year</option> 
    <option value="1910">1910</option> 
    <option value="1911">1911</option> 
    <option value="1912">1912</option> 
    <option value="1913">1913</option> 
    <option value="1914">1914</option> 
    <option value="1915">1915</option> 
    <option value="1916">1916</option> 
    <option value="1917">1917</option> 
    <option value="1918">1918</option> 
    <option value="1919">1919</option> 
    <option value="1920">1920</option> 
    <option value="1921">1921</option> 
    <option value="1922">1922</option> 
</select> 
</form>
```

> This is the working drop-down menu

```
<form method="get"  name="cityform">
    <select id="id_city" class="signup-location" name="city">
        <option value="select-city" selected="selected">select-city</option>  
        <option value="atlanta">Atlanta</option> 
        <option value="austin">Austin</option> 
        <option value="Baltimore">Baltimore</option> 
        <option value="Boston">Boston</option> 
        <option value="Brooklyn">Brooklyn </option> 
        <option value="Charlotte">Charlotte</option> 
        <option value="Chicago">Chicago</option> 
        <option value="Cincinnati">Cincinnati</option> 
        <option value="Cleveland">Cleveland</option> 
</select>
</form>
```

This Called when the activity is first created and the app is loaded.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.php");


    }
```

Comment: Are you sure you want to post it to a tml file instead of html file?

Comment: Yes i already have a webpage with the same form which submits the data to the tml file. I wanted to create the same registration form , right now for testing purpose I am pushing the data to the tml file so that I can see if the data is being submitted to the data-base.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works perfectly fine. How are you loading the html onto the WebView?

Comment: public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.php");

  
 }

Comment: I am not using any web view , simply loading the index.php which contains this form

Comment: How do you load the page? Please update your question with that code.

Comment: super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.php"); Which activity have you extended?

Comment: I got it to work kumar there was some css conflict with that particular field . thanks a lot for your help. I noticed one more thing since it is a huge list 1910-2010 it takes a lot of time to load in 2.2 emulator than a 3.2 , why is this so ?